# Where is the location of linuxbrew's log files?

Tags: linux, logs, homebrew

In MacOS, homebrew output logs to `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew`. What is the equivalent in Linux for [linuxbrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux)?

Answer (score 3):

Manage to find it in `~/.cache/Homebrew/Logs`

```
$ ls .cache/Homebrew/Logs/
app-engine-python  curl   gettext  ncurses     python
bazel          expat  git      openssl     python@2
binutils       gcc    glibc    percona-server  youtube-dl
bison          gdbm   mariadb  pkg-config
```